# \insertlecture in subtitle generates error but \insertlecturenumber does not

Tags: beamer, titles

In `beamer`, if I use `\insertlecture` in a subtitle I get:

```
Undefined control sequence \begin{document}
```

but the file compiles to PDF (with XeLaTeX) correctly anyway.

But I can use `\insertlecturenumber` with no error.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer} 
\let\Tiny=\tiny
\setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=OliveGreen!50!black} 
\usetheme{Madrid} 

\title[Title]{Long Title}
\subtitle{Lecture \insertlecturenumber : \insertlecture}

\AtBeginLecture{
\setcounter{framenumber}{0}
\begin{frame}[plain]
\titlepage
\end{frame}
}

\begin{document}

\lecture[LectShort]{LectLong}{1}

\begin{frame}
  Text
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

If I change:

```
\subtitle{Lecture \insertlecturenumber : \insertlecture}
```

To:

```
\subtitle{Lecture \insertlecturenumber}
```

It works with no error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've read somewhere (probably not far away) that some `beamer` commands are not valid until `\begin{document}` has been applied. I don't know why and don't know which commands, but I've tested with OP's code and it worked:

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer} 
\let\Tiny=\tiny
\setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=OliveGreen!50!black} 
\usetheme{Madrid} 

\AtBeginLecture{
\setcounter{framenumber}{0}
\begin{frame}[plain]
\titlepage
\end{frame}
}

\begin{document}
\title[Title]{Long Title} %<------ Moved to document body
\subtitle{Lecture \insertlecturenumber : \insertlecture} %<--- Moved to document body

\lecture[LectShort]{LectLong}{1}

\begin{frame}
  Text
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks that helps fix the problem, will test it on the dynamic bottom bar now.

Answer (score 2):

Since `\lecturename` is available after `\lecture` has been used, you can use it in your `\AtBeginLecture`:

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer} 
\let\Tiny=\tiny
\setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=OliveGreen!50!black} 
\usetheme{Madrid} 

\title[Title]{Long Title}

\AtBeginLecture{
\setcounter{framenumber}{0}
\subtitle{Lecture~\insertlecturenumber: \insertlecture}
\begin{frame}[plain]
\titlepage
\end{frame}
}

\begin{document}

\lecture[LectShort]{LectLong}{1}

\begin{frame}
  Text
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]